# Use SQL Access in Elasticsearch python client

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-py, elasticsearch-sql

I am trying to use the python client for elastic search to query an index using SQL access for elastic search. I want to query an index using sql syntax. How do i specify to elasticsearch that it has to read SQLsyntax?

```
 def searchText(text):
    t1 = time.time()
    es=Elasticsearch([{'host':'localhost','port':9200}])
    res =  es.search(index='global_res_todos_acco', size=10000, request_timeout=60,
                     body={'query':{
                                        "select * from global_res_todos_acco limit 100 where EntityList = " + text
                                    }
                          }
                     )
    GHList = []
    for hit in res['hits']['hits']:
            GHList.append(hit['_source']['Geohash7'])
    return(GHList)
```

i receive the following error in console

TypeError: Unable to serialize {'select * from global_res_todos_acco where EntityList = phuket indian food'}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using the Python client, you need to use the `es.sql.query()` function:

```
es=Elasticsearch([{'host':'localhost','port':9200}])
es.sql.query(body={'query': 'select * from global_res_todos_acco...'})
```